# return cur == NULL ? -1 : cur->val; (I am confused for this c++ sentence)

Tags: c++

```
    /** Helper function to return the index-th node in the linked list. */
SinglyListNode* getNode(int index) {
    SinglyListNode *cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index && cur; ++i) {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return cur;
}
/** Helper function to return the last node in the linked list. */
SinglyListNode* getTail() {
    SinglyListNode *cur = head;
    while (cur && cur->next) {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return cur;
}
/** Get the value of the index-th node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1. */
int get(int index) {
    SinglyListNode *cur = getNode(index);
    return cur == NULL ? -1 : cur->val;
}
```

---

This “ return cur == NULL ? -1 : cur->val; ”

I confused this syntax, can someone separate this sentence?

Comment: It is called **ternary operator**  or **conditional operator**. Take a look at : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a [ternary operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/ternary_operator_examples.htm). also known as a conditional operator.

This is used as a one liner condition statement.

this is equivalent to:

```
if (cur == NULL)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return cur->pos;
}
```

please refer to the above link for more information.

Comment: It is _a_ ternary operator, but more specifically it is _the_ conditional operator. And please don't post links to self-declared obsolete web pages.

Comment: SinglyListNode* getNode(int index) {
    SinglyListNode *cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index && cur; ++i)              How about   i<index && cur ???

Comment: @YuxiaoZheng • A pointer has an implicit conversion to a bool.  If the pointer is nullptr, it converts to false, otherwise converts to true.  It looks like you could use a good introductory book to C++, here's a curated list of good C++ books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list